# Handling multiple nodes when parsing XML with Python

Tags: python, mysql, xml

For an assignment, I need to parse through a 2 million line XML file, and input the data into a MySQL database. Since we are using a python environment with sqlite for the class, I am attempting to use python to parse the file. Keep in mind I am just learning python so everything is new!

I have had a few attempts, but keep failing and getting frustrated.
For efficiency, I am testing my code out on just a small amount of the full XML, here:

```
<pub>
<ID>7</ID>
<title>On the Correlation of Image Size to System Accuracy in Automatic Fingerprint Identification Systems</title>
<year>2003</year>
<booktitle>AVBPA</booktitle>
<pages>895-902</pages>
<authors>
    <author>J. K. Schneider</author>
    <author>C. E. Richardson</author>
    <author>F. W. Kiefer</author>
    <author>Venu Govindaraju</author>
</authors>
</pub>
```

**First attempt**

Here I successfully pulled out all data from each tag, except when there are multiple authors under the `<authors>` tag. I am trying to loop through each node in the authors tag, count, then create a temporary array for those authors, then throw them into my database next with SQL. I am getting "15" for the number of authors, but clearly there are only 4! How do I solve this?

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xmldoc= minidom.parse("test.xml")

pub = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("pub")[0]
ID = pub.getElementsByTagName("ID")[0].firstChild.data
title = pub.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].firstChild.data
year = pub.getElementsByTagName("year")[0].firstChild.data
booktitle = pub.getElementsByTagName("booktitle")[0].firstChild.data
pages = pub.getElementsByTagName("pages")[0].firstChild.data
authors = pub.getElementsByTagName("authors")[0]
author = authors.getElementsByTagName("author")[0].firstChild.data
num_authors = len(author)
print("Number of authors: ", num_authors )

print(ID)
print(title)
print(year)
print(booktitle)
print(pages)
print(author)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you were getting *the number of characters in the first author* here, for the code limits the result to only the first author (index 0) and then get its length :

```
author = authors.getElementsByTagName("author")[0].firstChild.data
num_authors = len(author)
print("Number of authors: ", num_authors )
```

Just don't limit the result to get all the authors :

```
author = authors.getElementsByTagName("author")
num_authors = len(author)
print("Number of authors: ", num_authors )
```

You can use *list comprehension* to get all author names, instead of author elements, in a list :

```
author = [a.firstChild.data for a in authors.getElementsByTagName("author")]
print(author)
# [u'J. K. Schneider', u'C. E. Richardson', u'F. W. Kiefer', u'Venu Govindaraju']
```

Comment: I knew I needed to access each variable in an array, but wasn't sure on the syntax. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey @har07 , so I made progress, but some of my XML data is "bad" in a sense... I have an entry with special characters like "í" in names, and come out to "&iacute;" in the XML file. How do I process these special language characters into python? The error I am getting is "ExpatError: undefined entity:".